# jquery find span with Numbers and hide it

Tags: jquery

How can I get the second **li** from the list and find in it a span with class "**txtlist**" which contains only numbers, and hide it?

```
<ul id="addresslist">
     <li>title</li>
     <li>
        <span class="txtlist">Full name</span> 
        <span class="txtlist">065632645454</span>
     </li>   
     <li>
        <span class="txtlist">USA</span> 
        <span class="txtlist">df sdfsdf g</span>
     </li>  
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Matching the second `<li>` element is pretty basic jQuery, did you manage to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concept behind this is, If we try to convert a `string` which can be convertible to a `number` would not return `NAN` while we using `+` for conversion.

Try,

```
$('ul li:eq(1) span.txtlist').filter(function(){
  return !isNaN(+$(this).text());
}).hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3q7X/)

Comment: Thank you!!! but this will hide any span that has number, I need it to work only for the second li

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#addresslist li').find('.txtlist').filter(function(){
    var get=parseInt($(this).html()) ? "num" : "no";
    if(get == "num" && $(this).index() == 1)
    {

       $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/5fFF3/1/)
this will hide only in second li